# Cron Advanced CSV Product Import Mapping

Tags: import, products, cron, magento-1, csv

I'm wondering how I could map a product CSV import including product attributes etc.

I need the CSV import to run daily via cron, as the CSV file is updated daily with product data.

I also need any products that aren't included in the CSV import to appear as out of stock in Magento.

Any idea what tools are out there that might allow me to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try Ho_Import (https://github.com/ho-nl/Ho_Import). Well developed, fully open source.

From their Github some use cases:
At the time of release we have this tool running for multiple clients, multiple types of imports:

- One time product / category imports from an old datasource Example config
- Periodic category import with values for multiple store views Example config
- 15 minute inventory only updates
- Nightly complete inventory updates Example config
- Nightly price updates
- Incremental category/product updates from ERP systems
- Customer import Example config
- Customer import with billing and shipping address Example config